# Adding a spacer block between king stud and switch box

Tags: electrical, door-frame

I'm framing a small wall to create some closet space. If I mount the light switch box directly to the king stud of the doorway, the door trim will interfere with the switch plate, so I wanted to bump the box out by putting a short scrap of 2x4 between the box and the king stud. Is there anything in the NEC that prohibits that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's common practice. As long as the framing member is rigidly attached it doesn't really matter what other function it serves or what it's called. (Jester stud?)